# Printing how much days left to a subscription?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the next question:
I have a table with a 'datetime' field in it called "last_payment", the thing i want to do is to show the users how much days left to their subscription (its a monthly subscription) so basically if the value in last_payment is "2011-06-10 12:28:11" and today its 15/06/2011 i want it to show that they have 25 days left.

I have the current code and it doesn't matter how much time i played with it it doesn't work when im trying to pull the data from the MySQL but it works when i do a "mktime()" function..:

```
$today = time();
$row_ct = mysql_fetch_array($result_ct);

//Subscription Counting Funcrion for Clients
$cdate_c = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2009, 0);
$difference_c = $today - $cdate_c;
if ($difference_c < 0) { $difference_c = 0; }
```

The following aren't working:

```
$cdate_c = mktime($row_ct["last_payment"]);
$cdate_c = mktime(strtotime($row_ct["last_payment"]));
$cdate_c = date(strtotime($row_ct["last_payment"]));
```

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`$cdate_c = strtotime($row_ct["last_payment"]);`

Answer (score 1):

`mktime` accepts 7 parameters, and returns false on invalid parameters. You only give it 1, so that is why these don't work:

```
$cdate_c = mktime($row_ct["last_payment"]);
$cdate_c = mktime(strtotime($row_ct["last_payment"]));
```

`date` accepts a format (how you want your time to look), and an optional timestamp. That is why you don't get anything for this:

```
$cdate_c = date(strtotime($row_ct["last_payment"]));
```

Try this related article: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Convert your dates to timestamps, calculate the difference in seconds, then calculate the number of seconds per day to determine the number of days for the difference.